# How to add the Authorization Token column in the input section of the settings (Pine Script v5)?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

This is the screenshot of settings dialog box of a Pine Script strategy. The creator[image] has provided authorization token column (for connecting to any algo trading provider) in the input section of the settings itself. Can anybody please mention which code can be used to get that and where? I'm new to pine script?

Please also note that after entering the Token here, the user has to mention {{strategy.oder.alert_message}} only in the message column of the Alert dialog box and its ready to fire signals to the Algo trading platform.

Today I added the following command:

token=input(defval="",title="Token",group="AUTOMATION"

As a result, though the token column appeared in the settings and alerts were generated, generating but they were not fired to (Tradetron) my Algo trading provider. Means there must be any programming linkage between the token and the alert_message. That is in between the two commands:

token=input(defval="",title="Token",group="AUTOMATION"

strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long,alert_message="1")

Is it so? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply `input.string()`.

The implementation depends on how the provider expects to receive the alert commands. There is no on generic code that works for all the providers.

Comment: I want to use strategy.order.alert_message command in the Alert message box.
My alert messages are:

    if (longEntryCondition)
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, alert_message 
         ="1")  

    if (longCloseCondition)
        strategy.close("Long", alert_message="-1")

    if (shortEntryCondition)
        strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, alert_message= 
        "2")
   
    if (shortCloseCondition)
        strategy.close("Short", alert_message="-2")

Comment: Please also note that after entering the Token here, the user has to mention {{strategy.oder.alert_message}} only in the message column of the Alert dialog box and its ready to fire signals to the Algo trading platform.

Comment: Please edit your original question and add new information there.

Comment: I edited my question and adding my own experimentation. Still I'm not getting any support.